# SQL - Yii - If one of foreign entries matches sort 1 if none sort 2

Tags: php, mysql, yii, case

I have a table `place` :

```
id | name
```

and a table `place_hours_opening` :

```
id | day | place_id | time_start | time_end | time_start2 | time_end2
```

NB :  `place 1 -> n place_hours_openging`

In order to order places (thanks to OrderBy) which are open right know before place which will open later (in chronological order) and because some others params come after.. I would like to attribute 1 if place is opened right now and 2 if not.

Currently I have :

```
  $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->with = array('placeHoursOpenings');
        $criteria->together = true;
        $criteria->select = array(

        "CASE
            WHEN (placeHoursOpenings.day = $yesterday AND
                ($ajdStart > $ajdEnd AND $hierFirst <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd )) THEN 1
            WHEN (placeHoursOpenings.day = $yesterday AND
                ($ajdStart2 > $ajdEnd2 AND $hierSecond <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd2) ) THEN 1
            WHEN (placeHoursOpenings.day = $day AND
                ($ajdStart > $ajdEnd AND $ajdStart <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $demEnd )) THEN 1
            WHEN (placeHoursOpenings.day = $day AND
                ($ajdStart < $ajdEnd AND $ajdStart <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd )) THEN 1
            WHEN (placeHoursOpenings.day = $day AND
                ($ajdStart2 > $ajdEnd2 AND $ajdStart2 <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $demEnd2 )) THEN 1
            WHEN (placeHoursOpenings.day = $day AND
                ($ajdStart2 < $ajdEnd2 AND $ajdStart2 <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd2 )) THEN 1
                ELSE 2
                END as opennow");
        $criteria->condition = "t.id = placeHoursOpenings.place_id";
```

The problem is that a place has several openings and although one returns 1 if the next returns 2 it erases the previous one..

In my mind, my logical, I think about a foreach like "Foreach openings for THIS place if ONE of the next conditions returns 1 ( = is true), attributes 1 for the entire and unique place".

I think about WHERE EXISTS but if not I couldn't attribute 2 and I still want that place.

How can I improve my statement ?

**EDIT SECOND TRY :**

I also try this :

```
CASE
            WHEN open = 1 THEN 1
                ELSE 2
                END as opennow
                FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(*) as open FROM place_hours_opening po
              WHERE po.place_id = t.id
              AND (
              (po.day = $yesterday AND
                $ajdStart > $ajdEnd AND $hierFirst <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd )
              OR (po.day = $yesterday AND
                $ajdStart2 > $ajdEnd2 AND $hierSecond <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd2)
              OR (po.day = $day AND
                $ajdStart > $ajdEnd AND $ajdStart <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $demEnd )
              OR (po.day = $day AND
                $ajdStart < $ajdEnd AND $ajdStart <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd )
              OR (po.day = $day AND
                $ajdStart2 > $ajdEnd2 AND $ajdStart2 <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $demEnd2 )
              OR(po.day = $day AND
                $ajdStart2 < $ajdEnd2 AND $ajdStart2 <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd2 )
              )
              ) as opalias
```

But I got a generical error :

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `placeHoursOpenings`.`id`
```

Maybe I forgot a comma ? I am mistaken somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me.

If it can help someone else :

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->with = array('placeHoursOpenings');
        $criteria->together = true;
        $criteria->select = array(
        "CASE
            WHEN (
            SELECT COUNT(*) as open FROM place_hours_opening po
              WHERE po.place_id = t.id

              AND (
              (po.day = $yesterday AND
                $ajdStart > $ajdEnd AND $hierFirst <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd )
              OR (po.day = $yesterday AND po.time_start2 IS NOT NULL AND
                $ajdStart2 > $ajdEnd2 AND $hierSecond <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd2)
              OR (po.day = $day AND
                $ajdStart > $ajdEnd AND $ajdStart <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $demEnd )
              OR (po.day = $day AND
                $ajdStart < $ajdEnd AND $ajdStart <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd )
              OR (po.day = $day AND po.time_start2 IS NOT NULL AND
                $ajdStart2 > $ajdEnd2 AND $ajdStart2 <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $demEnd2 )
              OR(po.day = $day AND po.time_start2 IS NOT NULL AND
                $ajdStart2 < $ajdEnd2 AND $ajdStart2 <= '$date' AND '$date' <= $ajdEnd2 )
              )
              ) = 1 THEN 1
                ELSE 2
                END as opennow
        ");
        $criteria->condition = "t.id = placeHoursOpenings.place_id";

        if($sort == 2) {
            $criteria->order = "opennow ASC";
        }


        $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith($criteria);

        return $this;
```

**Other things to take into account :**

- I must use  `$criteria->select = array("something", "else")` instead of just `$criteria->select = "something, else")` because I actually use two SQL CASE in this select (not presents in my above sample code for clearness). Without **array** the second CASE is interpreted like a column name.
- I formate my dates thanks to CdbExpression and STR_TO_STRING :

  ```
   $ajdStart = new CDbExpression("STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('$todayDate', po.time_start),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')");
  ```

Hope this helps.